# AVPlayer error with url

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

I am using the `AVPlayer` for playing the video. But my problem i.e, the the player is occurring the error. while the same url is already to play in to the `Android` device and Safari web browser also. If this url replaced by the other url it's working fine.

This is the error.

> player.error==========>>>>>>>>>>Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11848 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x156d78f30 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12925 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The media cannot be used on this device., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open})

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            let videoUrl = "http://telvuehls_t03007-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/217085/T03007-calkins/playlist.m3u8"
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: videoUrl as String)!)
            let playerObj = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

            self.player = playerObj
            if playerItem.error == nil{
                playerObj.play()
            }else{
               print("player.error==========>>>>>>>>>>\(playerItem.error)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show some code what exactly you doing wrong?

Comment: Also mention the url in which you are getting this error

Comment: @Rajat I have mention my code above.

Comment: @Sanjeetverma I have mentioned the url in my code.

Comment: Implement observer for `AVPlayer` to track status info, refer this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539567/avplayer-got-the-metadata-but-not-playing/16542434#16542434). Start playing video when player is ready as you are playing HLS stream which is different than local video playback.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara, the observer also implemented. but it responds to me 'AVPlayerItemStatus.Unknown' and 'AVPlayerItemStatus.Failed'.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the  following link [Supportable Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986105/1142743) for supportable formats of `AVPlayer`

I think the format you are using to play is not able to open by `AVPlayer` which is clearly mentioned in the error.

As for i know `AVPlayer` need chunk of data to play.